# Matplotlib: determining when mouse is in axis text rectangle

Tags: python, matplotlib, zooming

So it's somewhat well known that in matplotlib zoom, pressing 'x' or 'y' when zooming will zoom on only the x or y axis.  I would like to modify this slightly by subclassing the NavigationToolbar2 in backend_bases.py

Specifically, I would like to have the functionality that if the mouse is in the region on the canvas below a plot (or above, depending on where I have put my axes), or to the left or right of the plot, to choose to zoom with _zoom_mode = 'x' or 'y'.  (In addition to keeping the default zoom to rect functionality when the mouse is inside the plot.)

Looking at backend_bases, it appears the method I need to modify is press_zoom

```
def press_zoom(self, event):
    if event.button=1:
            self._button_pressed=1
    elif  event.button == 3:
        self._button_pressed=3
    else:
        self._button_pressed=None
        return

    x, y = event.x, event.y

    # push the current view to define home if stack is empty
    if self._views.empty(): self.push_current()

    self._xypress=[]
    for i, a in enumerate(self.canvas.figure.get_axes()):
        if (x is not None and y is not None and a.in_axes(event) and
            a.get_navigate() and a.can_zoom()) :
            self._xypress.append(( x, y, a, i, a.viewLim.frozen(),
                                   a.transData.frozen() ))

    id1 = self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.drag_zoom)

    id2 = self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',
                                  self._switch_on_zoom_mode)
    id3 = self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event',
                                  self._switch_off_zoom_mode)

    self._ids_zoom = id1, id2, id3

    self._zoom_mode = event.key


    self.press(event)
```

and add an elif to the big if statement there and use it to set the zoom mode there, but what I cannot figure out (yet), is how to tell if the mouse is in the region appropriate for 'x' or 'y' zoom mode.

So, how can I tell when the mouse is just outside of a plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By converting the x and y coordinate into Axes coordinates. You can tell if they're just outside the axes, if they're less than 0 or larger than 1.

Here is a simple example of how it could work.

```
def is_just_outside(fig, event):
    x,y = event.x, event.y
    print x, y
    for ax in fig.axes:
        xAxes, yAxes =  ax.transAxes.inverted().transform([x, y])
        print xAxes, yAxes
        if  (-0.02 < xAxes < 0) | (1 < xAxes < 1.02):
            print "just outside x-axis"
        if  (-0.02 < yAxes < 0) | (1 < yAxes < 1.02):
            print "just outside y-axis"

x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda e: is_just_outside(fig, e))
plt.show()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  I was not aware of how to get the axes coordinates in that manner.  Thank you.